# Spring-WebFlux code to save per-user data

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring-WebFlux with Spring-Security and I need to save data depending on the currently registered user. In order to do so, in my controller, I need to retrieve the data sent from both the frontend and the principal.

After searching for a solution to my problem on the internet, I didn't find any clear way to do what I wanted, so I did my own stuff but I don't know whether it's correct.

Here's what I did:

```
public Mono<Order> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<OrderViewModel> orderViewModel, Mono<Principal> principal) {
    return principal.flatMap(userPrincipal ->
        orderViewModel.flatMap(order -> this.orderService.save(order, userPrincipal))
    );
}
```

As you can see, I have two `Mono` objects in my controller. Then, I kind of nest them one in the other by performing two `flatMap()` calls in order to return my `Mono` response.

Well, it works fine but I'm a beginner with WebFlux and I really don't know if this solution is "dirty" or valid. If you guys have any better approach I'll be happy to discuss it. Otherwise I hope this code fragment can help those with similar problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problems at all with the supplied code.

Nesting multiple `Mono`s is no problems and `flatMap`ing over them in a nested fashion is somewhat common.